# Bound of Chebyshev function and zeros of zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, zeta-functions

It is an elementary argument (such as in Multiplicative Number Theory, section 18) that, if the Chebyshev's function $f(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(x) = x + O(x^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha < 1$, then there's no zeros of zeta function whose real part is greater than $\alpha$. Without assuming GRH, what is the best possible known bound for $\alpha$ to date?

Comment: No such $\alpha$ is known unconditionally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has already been answered in a comment.